# Determining Binary Offset to a Pointer in Assembler/IDA

Tags: assembly, ida

See http://pastebin.com/QLywfZYK for the relevant disassembled code in `IDA`.
My question is which is the correct binary offset to get the pointer `dword_1082FF28` when starting from the function signature `(55 8B EC 83 EC 1C ...)`.

I'm reasonably certain it was 13 (thirteen), because that's what i get when i start with 55 = 1 and keep counting until i hit 28, which is where the pointer address starts. Is that correct?

I have only very rudimentary assembler knowledge, enough to scout out signatures if I need them, but not actually enough to READ the code.

Comment: The pastebin link is down, so the question you are asking is unclear.  Regardless, you can display addresses as function offsets in IDA, assuming this is what you want.  `Options > General > Function Offsets`

Answer (score 0):

Normally offsets start at 0 so the offset from the start of your function (55h) would be 12 (0Ch).  Adding 12 to the address of your function gives the address of the pointer.

Comment: Thanks, atleast it's not something crazy like counting the bytes from back to front or something ... 12 or 13 i can trial-and-error if i have to